error running example qt applications on a remote linux device (v3s in this case)
I'm trying to run a sample qt application on a v3s with Linux ARMHF architecture.
I've successfully built a qt version 6.4.2 and add ARMHF compilers with cmake version 3.28.3
the v3s kit looks like ok and works without error.
I added a remote device with ssh key as a v3s-device and test it's within qt creator ide and everything works fine.


when I click on any samples, qt asks for configure project for kits that defined.
the desktop kit is ok, and I've successfully run sample
but on v3s kit I have the following error:
Error: the build device "v3s-device" cannot reach the project directory.

any helpful idea will be appreciated.
I add host public key to remote device and vice versa because I thought that maybe remote device wants to access project directory that is on host, but the issue is still remaining.
